# Center image and fix to pixel

Tags: html, css

I have a pixel fit designed icon, but it shows a not desired antialias effect depending on the width of the viewport.

This is the icon fixed to pixel:

[image]

And antialiased:

[image]

(provisonal site to see it: https://stage.quercusoficinasydespachos.com/)

The problem seems to be that container div is centered and the browser calculates its position from viewport width. If the viewport has a odd amount of pixels, it results in a fractional number.

This is my actual markup:

```
    <div class="column">
      <div>
         <a>@svg('desk')</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.column {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        max-width: 600px;
}
```

Is it possible to center the image rounding it to pixel? Thanks!

**[EDIT] It happens on Firefox OSX. Chrome render icons fixed to pixel.**

Comment: have you tried addied the vendor for firebox? https://www.lifewire.com/css-vendor-prefixes-3466867

Comment: Yes, I'm using autoprefixer.